# Refreshable Bean no Last-Modified Header

Tags: spring, groovy

In my application context file I have a Groovy "refreshable" bean defined. The bean is defined with an http: prefix (see below). The problem I'm having is that our web servers do not send the last-modified header, which the refreshable bean requires to determine if the script has been modified.

I need to host the scripts on our web servers, and I can't modify the server config to send the last-modified header. So the only option I can think of is to manually force a refresh by calling some method on the bean.

Is there any way, given the bean below, that I can force a refresh?

```
<lang:groovy id="messenger" refresh-check-delay="1000" 
        script-source="http://10.74.192.111/groovy/GroovyMessenger.groovy" />
```

Could I maybe create a GroovyObjectCustomizer that would add a forceRefresh method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem should be fixed if you replace the standard implementation of the script factory post processor bean.

The explanation would be quite long, and it would be the same idea as
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-groovierspring1.html
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-groovierspring2.html
http://www.springone2gx.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2010/10/database_backed_refreshable_beans_with_groovy_and_spring_3
Last link is an addition to the original series in case you are using spring 3 (which i believe should be your case)

In short, you would want a different kind of `org.springframework.scripting.ScriptSource`, one that always returns `true` when asked if modified. The standard implementation would ask the underlying `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` implementation and in your case,
return `false` as result of checking the header contents of an http head request. You can do this with a custom `org.springframework.scripting.support.ScriptFactoryPostProcessor`.

But again, check the articles there. They include a highly detailed explanation of the changes required.

Comment: From my understanding, having isModified return true each time should cause the script to be reloaded every time it is used.  I need some way to trigger that a script has been modified, and cause a reload.  I think I may just use the database solution mentioned in the articles.

Comment: @Steve  
I believe the first thing that is checked is the refresh delay.  
So if you set a refresh delay of an hour, the script will only be cheched for modification when the hour has passed.